# PHP Get URL without Query String - While Modifiying existing query

Tags: php, string, url, replace, echo

Long time lurker first time poster here:

I have searched high and low and am trying to keep my php script somewhat the same as it is:

```
$url = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

however when I echo $url I need to:

1. Remove the string from `www.example.com/?utm_source=etc`
   removing everything after `/?` on multiple file names like
   `www.example.com/page.htm/?utm_source=etc` 
   `www.example.com/page1.htm/?utm_source=etc`
   and so on
2. Keep the google custom search query string `www.example.com/search.htm?q=term`
3. Keep a couple other search string close the GSE string example

Ive seen some examples but none worked for me without making a ton of changes, surley there is a easier way.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try splitting your string into an array with the `/` or `?` symbol (example: `$your_array = explode("?", $your_string);`) and then use what you need from that array.

Comment: maybe interesting? [League\Url is a simple library to ease URL parsing and editing in PHP](http://url.thephpleague.com/3.0/). Examples: [The Query class - examples](http://url.thephpleague.com/3.0/components/query/)

Comment: @Frank - will you accept my answer or you need more help, thank you?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job for you. I used php regex and `preg_replace()` predefined function for it.

Regex (Fiddle [Link](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/cq1))

```
/www(\.)[A-Za-z0-9]+\.\w+(\/)(\?)?((\w)+(\.)(\w)+)?((.)+)?/i
```

Php example

```
 <?php
    $input_line = 'www.example.com/?utm_source=etc'; //Input String
    $replace_String = ''; //specify your replace string here
    $regex = preg_replace("/www(\.)[A-Za-z0-9]+\.\w+(\/)(\?)?((\w)+(\.)(\w)+)?((.)+)?/i", $replace_String, $input_line);
    print_r($regex); //this will print the output with replaced string
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split url into different pieces and then put all of it back together - this is the only way.

So for example if your url is

```
    $url = www.example.com/page1.htm/?utm_source=etc&some_key=some_key_value&someothekey=someotherid

    $url_array = explode("?",$url);

    $url_path = $url_array[0];
    $url_params = explode("&",$url_array[1]);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($url_params as $url_param){ // Let's get specific url parameter and it's value
        $i++;

        $url_key = explode("=",$url_param)[0];
        $url_value = explode("=",$url_param)[1];
        $some_key = "some_key"; 

/*
 * or use $i auto increment to find, relevant search parameter based on position e.g. 
 * if($i = 0){ // 0 is first etc.
 *    $some_key = $url_key;
 * }
 */

        // now that we have all keys - let's compare
        if($url_key === $some_key){

           $some_key_value .= $url_value; // Note the dot before ".=" so you can use it outside the loop, do the same if statements for any other keys you need 
        }     


    }

    $new_url = $url_path."?".$some_key."=".$some_key_value;
```

Comment: Jijo - my way is not the only way...but to rebuild a string using someold and some new parameters is have to be some kind of a super glue lol :v